# Auto complete não funciona por qual motivo e por que?

Tags: php, html, jquery

Por que minha busca não funciona?

```
 $(document).ready( function(){

 var cidades=[], bairros=[];

  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'curtida.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){

      for(var i in response){

       if(response[i].cidade!=null && response[i].bairro!=null){
        cidades +=response[i].cidade+","; 

        bairros +=response[i].bairro+",";   
        }

    }
      $("#cidade").autocomplete({
          source: cidades,
          minLength: 1
        });

        $("#bairro").autocomplete({
          source: bairros,
          minLength: 1
        });

        console.log(cidades);
        console.log(bairros);


        }

    });



  } );
```

**PHP**

```
   $sql_cidade_cidade= ("SELECT DISTINCT cidade FROM  Teste_cidade");// comando ser executado
    $retorno_cidade_cidade = $conn->query($sql_cidade_cidade);

 $sql_cidade_bairro= ("SELECT DISTINCT bairro FROM  Teste_bairro");// comando ser executado
$retorno_cidade_bairro = $conn->query($sql_cidade_bairro);


  while (($exibir_dados= mysqli_fetch_assoc($retorno_cidade_cidade))!==($pega_campo= mysqli_fetch_assoc($retorno_cidade_bairro))) { 
     $dados[] = array(
         'cidade'=>$exibir_dados['cidade'],
         'bairro'=>$pega_campo['bairro'], 
     ); 

        }


           echo json_encode($dados);
```

**HTML**

```
                    <div class="col-sm-6 ui-widget"  >
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">  <label  class="control-label" for="cidade"> Cidade:</label></span>
                         <input  id="cidade" name="cidade" type="text" maxlength="200" class="form-control"  placeholder="Digite a Cidade" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 ui-widget ">

                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">   <label  class="control-label" for="bairro"> Bairro:</label></span>

                           <input id ="bairro" name="bairro" type="text" maxlength="200"  class="form-control"  placeholder="Digite o Bairro">
                    </div>

                     <div class="col-sm-12 ">
                         <br>
                         <button onclick="pesquisaIndex()"  type="button" name="buscar" class="btn btn-primary"  >Buscar</button>
                     </div>
             </form>
```

Comment: Faz um [mcve], por favor. Para achar o erro na sua pergunta atual, só analisando o código inteiro, mas para isso teríamos que cobrar a consultoria :D

Comment: Serio, obrigado deixa pra próxima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Garanta que os dados do servidor vêm assim:

```
bairros=["bairro1","bairro2",...]

cidades=["cidade1","cidade2",...]
```

E ajustaria o JS para o seguinte, garantindo que só é ativado o autocomplete se o pedido AJAX for bem sucedido e tiver dados:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cidades = [],
        bairros = [];

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'curtida.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {

            for (var i in response) {

                if (response[i].cidade != null && response[i].bairro != null) {
                    cidades += response[i].cidade + ",";

                    bairros += response[i].bairro + ",";
                }

            }

            console.log(cidades);
            console.log(bairros);
        },
        complete: function () {
            if (cidades && bairros) {
                $("#cidade").autocomplete({
                    source: cidades,
                    minLength: 1
                });

                $("#bairro").autocomplete({
                    source: bairros,
                    minLength: 1
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Então estou errado por bobeira ?

Comment: resolvi  mano  sua dica me deu um norte, muito obrigado!

Comment: Ainda bem que resolveu! Se a minha resposta inicial ajudou aceita como a resposta correta por favor